# Blazorise Vertical Sidebar Toggle

Tags: blazor, blazorise

I'm using the [Blazorise](https://blazorise.com/) component library, and I'd like to make a vertical sidebar similar to the way it's done here: https://www.matblazor.com/, where it's always collapsed unless you click the toggler. It seems simple enough but I just can't figure it out.

Of course I'm using the [Layout component](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/layout/) with the Sider and the [Bar component](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/bar/), but I can't get the `BarToggler` to always show and control the sidebar properly.

Answer (score 0):

To make `BarToggler` always visible you can set the CSS display property to inline-flex. If you are using bootstrap, you can also make the bar menu items never collapse by adding the `navbar-expand` css class. Example:

```
@*Header bar*@
<Bar Class="navbar-expand"
     Background="Background.Light"
     ThemeContrast="ThemeContrast.Light">

    <BarToggler Display="Display.InlineFlex" Border="Border.Is0" Clicked="ToggleSidebar" />

    <BarBrand>
        Brandname
    </BarBrand>

    <BarMenu>
        <BarStart>
            <BarItem>
                <BarLink To="#home">Home</BarLink>
            </BarItem>
            <BarItem>
                <BarLink To="#docs">Documentation</BarLink>
            </BarItem>
            <BarItem>
                <BarDropdown>
                    <BarDropdownToggle>Dropdown</BarDropdownToggle>
                    <BarDropdownMenu>
                        <BarDropdownItem>Action</BarDropdownItem>
                        <BarDropdownDivider />
                        <BarDropdownItem>Another action</BarDropdownItem>
                    </BarDropdownMenu>
                </BarDropdown>
            </BarItem>
        </BarStart>
        <BarEnd>
            <BarItem>
                <Button Color="Color.Primary">Sign up</Button>
                <Button Color="Color.Secondary">Log in</Button>
            </BarItem>
        </BarEnd>
    </BarMenu>
</Bar>

@*Sider bar*@
<Bar Mode="BarMode.VerticalInline"
     Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Desktop"
     Background="Background.Primary"
     ThemeContrast="ThemeContrast.Dark"
     @bind-Visible="_sidebarVisible">

...

</Bar>

@code {
    private bool _sidebarVisible;

    private void ToggleSidebar()
    {
        _sidebarVisible = !_sidebarVisible;
    }
}
```

Use the following layout and place header bar inside `<LayoutHeader>` and sider bar inside `<LayoutSiderContent>` to achieve a layout similar to the matblazor page.

```
<Layout>
    <LayoutHeader>
        Header
    </LayoutHeader>
    <Layout Sider>
        <LayoutSider>
            <LayoutSiderContent>
                Sider
            </LayoutSiderContent>
        </LayoutSider>
        <Layout>
            <LayoutContent>
                Content
            </LayoutContent>
        </Layout>
    </Layout>
</Layout>
```

[image: Screenshot]